# How to fix VS Code error while loading images?

Tags: windows, image, visual-studio-code

Any time I try to use an image from my local machine, I get an error from VS Code saying "An error occurred while loading the image. Open file using vs code's standard text/binary editor."
The original drag and drop of the image into the file functions as in I can see the image in the text editor but if I click onto another file/folder and back onto the image file, I get this error. This is happening in this instance while trying to use a .ico file but it has been happening for about a week now with any image I try to use (.png, .ico, .jpg, etc...). I am on a Windows 10 machine and memory is not an issue.

I have tried disabling all extensions, replacing the file with another, making sure VS Code is up to date and completely closing VS Code and re-opening it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got the same issue last week, and this was how I fixed it:

Go to where you saved the project on your laptop, then drag and drop the images there. This should reflect in your VS Code.

Once the images were added through this route, they would not bring the initial error.

Let me know if you got what I said or if a short video will help!

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue and I did the one above and it didn't work. So I was browsing around my local machine to see what I can do and that's when I found a better way to solve it.

In HTML syntax, you are supposed to type . At src you would copy the file path and paste it there. But here VSCode works a bit different.

Drag and Drop the image from your local machine into the file explorer section of the IDE. Then go to the image which will be there in a new tab and right click it. It would get you many options out of which copy the Relative path and paste it in src in above syntax.

Reason for using Relative path is that the image is in VSCode and being used from there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I tried to reinstall but it still does not work.

I found that using another extension will be OK. Install the "Image Gallery" from GeriYoco, and set the default editor for the image to "Image Gallery".

[image]

[image]